# ExtJs Tpl not getting shown

Tags: templates, extjs

Just want to get the `tpl` text show, even though component renders successfully but have no text inside. Seem blank on screen

```
Ext.Component({ 
    ...  
    tpl: 'Hi let me show on screen please',  
});
```

Why am not getting shown any thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates expect the `data` property to be defined:

```
var foo = new Ext.Component({
    renderTo: document.body,
    tpl: 'foo baroo',
    data: {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/modern/Ext.Component.html#cfg-tpl)

**The data configuration must be set for any content to be shown in the component when using this configuration.**

As per your code you are not binding data and there for you not getting result.

sample code should be like :

```
Ext.Component({ 
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
tpl: ['<ul class="details">',
        '<li><b>Name:</b> {Name}</li>',
        '<li><b>Email:</b> {Email}</li>',
    '</ul>'],
data: {
    Name: 'User-1',
    Email: 'user-1@gmail.com'
}
});
```